# CSS transition removing border-radius property

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am creating a CSS transition that scale the inner element when the parent state is hover.

However the parent has a `border-radius` property that does not get forced on the actual hover itself. When the user is hovering the element there is no border-radius shown.

I figure out that has to do with the overflow, I tried to have a `z-index` for the parent to be higher than the child one but had no luck.

My fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/muLhkx9m/1/

Comment: This issue occurs in safari browser and seems working fine in chrome browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is a known bug with the transitions and backface visibility.
To be more specific - the scale transitions often need one more "browser hack" to function properly - and that is

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

I have added this to your fiddle, to the .box element and check for yourself how it works :)

[Your Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muLhkx9m/2/)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much